# Return number of selected elements with jQuery UI Selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm using jQuery Selectable (http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/) and need to know the number of elements selected once the operation is complete.

```
//Example Code
$('body').selectable({
    selected: function(event,ui) {
       var $selectedItems = ui.selected;
       alert($selectedItems.length); // This is always 1
    }
});
```

The variable "selectedItems" returns the elements that are selected. I can loop through them like this:

```
$selectedItems.each( function() {
    // do something
});
```

But I simply want to know how many elements are selected.

The "length" property always returns 1. And it doesn't seem right to put a counter in the above loop. There must be some way of doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in a `$(document).ready(function() { //your code }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run one callback after the selections are made and check how many selections there are, you can use the `stop` event instead.  This is run once after the selection is done.  Then, you can check the number of selected items by the class that's added, namely `ui-selected`.

```js
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
    stop: function(event,ui) {
       var selectedItems = $('.ui-selected', this);
       console.log(selectedItems.length);
    }
});
```

```css
  #selectable .ui-selecting {
    background: #ccc;
  }
  #selectable .ui-selected {
    background: #999;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<ul id="selectable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```